# R function; if input is not given, ask for it

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function in R that takes two inputs as strings. If neither input is set, it asks for the inputs and then continues the function.

```
Input < - function(j,k){
   if ((j==j)&&(k==k)){
      j <- readline(prompt="Enter Input 1: ")
      k <- readline(prompt="Enter Input 2: ")
      Input(j,k)
   }else if ((j=="<string here>")&&(k=="<string here>")){
      ....
   }
}
```

Comment: Would you clarify what "neither input is set" means? Most of the answers assume this means if either one is not set, so have "or" logic in the first line, but you have "and" logic. It seems more likely though that you want to check them separately; that is, if `j` is missing, ask for `j`, and if `k` is missing, ask for `k`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think the better way to structure your approach would be this, using optional arguments and testing to see if they are non-null before proceeding, though admittedly your posted question is very vague:

```
Input < - function(j=NA, k=NA) {
  if (is.na(j) | is.na(k)){
    j <- readline(prompt="Enter Input 1: ")
    k <- readline(prompt="Enter Input 2: ")
    Input(j, k)
  } else if ((j == "<string here>") & (k == "<string here>")) {
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: I think `NULL` is preferred for optional function arguments - see e.g. `plot.default` - then you can test using `is.null`

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be preferred in this case?  At the best it would be equivalent but irrelevant?  In fact, as I look at it again the preferred default value might be an empty string if you'd like the function to re-ask for input values if the user did not type anything at one or both of the prompts.

Comment: It may not make stuff-all difference in this case, but it could cause issues depending on expectations, e.g. `NULL` is nothing, no length, while `NA` is a length==1, logical class vector. They are not really equivalent, but it's a minor issue here. Not looking to start any big argument.

Comment: No, obviously they aren't equal, but in this case I should have specified they are functionally equivalent. I agree though, given the vagueness of the question using one or the other could potentially matter, but I just don't think it does as it was coded above or implied by the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Although I personally prefer the `is.NA` or `is.NULL` (as in @Forrest 's answer), this is an alternative with `missing` that might look simpler for someone starting now with R.

```
Input <- function(j, k) {
  if (missing(j) | missing(k)){
    j <- readline(prompt="Enter Input 1: ")
    k <- readline(prompt="Enter Input 2: ")
    Input(j, k)
  } else if ((j == "<string here>") & (k == "<string here>")) {
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case you could not actually call the Input() function without supplying some value for the `j` and `k` arguments.  They could never be missing since you've specified them as non-optional arguments.

Comment: This function works for me (R version 3.2.0).  I don't think R actually requires arguments to exist in functions unless they are used in some way.  Try `u<-function(x) print(1);u()`.

Comment: Yes, that's well known and good behavior on R's part.  But this won't work: `u<-function(x) {x==x;print(1)};u()` and the function as it's written above won't run unless `j` and `k` are passed since they are both not given defaults and used inside the function declaration.

Comment: @ForrestR.Stevens The above function will work. This is the reason `missing()` exists in the first place. You don't need to pre-define them. Try writing a function with the first four lines and then just print the value to see.

Comment: Ah, I feel like an idiot, but better informed.  Thanks for pointing that out!  In running your example I did find a space in your assignment operator that should be removed.

Comment: @ForrestR.Stevens Whoooops! you are right. It is partly my fault for confusing you :P. I fixed the code. But don't worry. This is the good thing about stack overflow, it makes us learn by trying things! I ve learnt a lot in a similar way :)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's simplest perhaps to put the `readline` code as the argument. The `force` commands force evaluation of that code at that point in the function. I don't think they're necessary but depending what else the function does, you may want to make sure that it's asking for `j` and `k` first instead of later; otherwise the code will be evaluated when it first needs to know what `j` and `k` are.

```
Input <- function(j = readline(prompt="Enter Input 1: "),
                  k = readline(prompt="Enter Input 2: ")) {
    force(j)
    force(k)
    if ((j=="<string here>") && (k=="<string here>")) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution as it eliminates the explicit if/then check on j/k. I think `force()` is one of those functions you'd never know about or need unless you're fighting some hard to track down scoping bugs, but definitely nice to illustrate here.